# Android Twitter App - none work

Tags: android, twitter

Wow, Ive been trying to get a simple Android Twitter app to work but its been impossible.  I come from an iOS background.  Im currently trying to make these work:

1. MyTwitter app from Marakana.  http://marakana.com/forums/android/examples/312.html
2. Marakana Simple OAuth demo.    https://github.com/marakana/OAuthDemo
3. Twitter4j Sample itog_lab.  https://github.com/itog/Twitter4j-android-Sample
4. AndroidTwitterSample.  http://www.android10.org/index.php/articleslibraries/291-twitter-integration-in-your-android-application#josc329

I always get unauthorized error unable to request access token.  Has anyone had this experience?

Comment: Have you gone through all of the twitter4j library example code? Just use that and you are on the road to success. http://twitter4j.org/en/code-examples.html

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you are content with calling Twitter using Intent (meaning that you will need the Twitter app already installed for this to work), you can access Twitter with something like this:

```
try{
    Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_SEND);
    intent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_TEXT, "It's a Tweet!" + "#MyApp");
    intent.setType("text/plain");
    final PackageManager pm = getPackageManager();
    final List<?> activityList = pm.queryIntentActivities(intent, 0);
    int len =  activityList.size();
    for (int i = 0; i < len; i++) {
        final ResolveInfo app = (ResolveInfo) activityList.get(i);
        if ("com.twitter.android.PostActivity".equals(app.activityInfo.name)) {
            final ActivityInfo activity=app.activityInfo;
            final ComponentName name=new ComponentName(activity.applicationInfo.packageName, activity.name);
            intent=new Intent(Intent.ACTION_SEND);
            intent.addCategory(Intent.CATEGORY_LAUNCHER);
            intent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK | Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_RESET_TASK_IF_NEEDED);
            intent.setComponent(name);
            intent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_TEXT, "It's a Tweet!" + "#MyApp");
            startActivity(intent);
            break;
        }
    }
} catch(final ActivityNotFoundException e) {
    Log.i("Twitter intent", "no twitter native", e );
}
```

Comment: Robert-I downloaded a twitter4j sample but I'll try the one u posted.  Phil-what do u mean by "am I content using an intent to connect?  How else could I connect?  As for the downvote, I have no idea who gave it...I didn't even know you could assign downvotes.

Comment: @mars, if you already have the twitter app installed, you should be able to use the code above, instead of fussing with OAUTH, or other means of authentication.

Comment: You mean if i have the twitter app installed on my android phone? I dont have an android phone, Im testing everything out in the eclipse emulators. I finally got the marakana OAuthDemo to work with the key & secret that it came with, which belongs to an app producer, Marko Gargenta

Comment: yeah, this would have to be on an android phone. Anyway, glad to hear you got something working.

Comment: this doesn't work if you have the twitter app opened before tweeting... it will take you straight to the app, but without dialog.

Answer (score 0):

my example works http://schwiz.net/blog/2011/using-scribe-with-android/ ping me if you run into trouble.

Comment: the app closes unexpectedly...im running it on sdk 10

Comment: @mars did you set your api key/secret?  An exception will be thrown if not.  I have ran the project on sdk 10 with no issues.  If you continue to have problems feel free to email me a stacktrace or pastebin it here or on my blog. gl